# Use wordpress function in PHP file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress Child Theme and I use a php file as the template for a particular page.

I am trying to implement an API for a plugin called GeoIP Detection. Please see the PHP file I am using on my site below. The API I am trying to apply is "Redirect depending on country" located [here](https://github.com/yellowtree/wp-geoip-detect/wiki/API-Usage-Examples)

When I load the script, I am supposed to be redirected to `https://www.google.com.sg` However, it does not do so.

Thank you.

**My PHP**

```
<?php /* Template Name: GeoIPDetectionv3 */

add_action('template_redirect', 'geoip_redirect', 5);
function geoip_redirect(){
    if (is_admin())
        return;

    // This condition prevents a redirect loop:
    // Redirect only if the home page is called. Change this condition to the specific page or URL you need.
    if (!is_page(90))
        return;

    if (!function_exists('geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip'))
        return;

    $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    $countryCode = $userInfo->country->isoCode;
    switch ($countryCode) {
        case 'DE':
            $url = '/germany';
            break;
        case 'US':
            $url = '/usa';
            break;
        case 'SG':
            $url = 'https://www.google.com.sg';
            break;
        default:
            $url = 'https://www.google.com.sg';
    }
    if ($url) {
        wp_redirect(get_current_blog_id(null, $url));
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like it's a question for [WordPress.se].

Comment: The output is not an error, it's actual text

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, would try my luck there as well thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single PHP tag, and make sure the last portion of your code is in fact inside a PHP tag. Currently it is not, so it's parsed as plain text.

**UPDATE:** I've cleaned this up a bit for you and updated the code to reflect your revised question; i.e., following our comments below.

```
<?php /* Template Name: GeoIPDetectionv3 */

add_action('template_redirect', 'geoip_redirect', 5);

function geoip_redirect(){
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return; // Not applicable.
    }
    if ( 123 !== get_current_blog_id() ) {
        return; // Not on blog ID 123.
    }
    if ( ! is_page( 90 ) ) {
        return; // Not a specific page ID on this blog.
    }
    if ( ! function_exists( 'geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $userInfo    = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    $countryCode = $userInfo->country->isoCode;

    switch ($countryCode) {
        case 'DE':
            $redirect_to = '/germany';
            break;
        case 'US':
            $redirect_to = '/usa';
            break;
        case 'SG':
            $redirect_to = 'https://www.google.com.sg';
            break;
        default:
            $redirect_to = 'https://www.google.com.sg';
    }
    if ( ! empty( $redirect_to ) ) {
        if ( stripos( $redirect_to, 'http' ) === 0 ) {
            wp_redirect( $redirect_to ); // Full URL.
        } else {
            wp_redirect( home_url( $redirect_to ) ); // Local /path.
        }
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi jaswrks, appreciate the reply. I cannot take away the `<?php /* Template Name: GeoIPDetection */?>` portion of the script otherwise wordpress would not allow me to select it as the template for the page. Also, I cannot place the PHP file in MU plugin folder as I am using a Child theme and according to this site (`www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/`), I need to place the PHP file here `/wp-content/themes/ directory`. Nevertheless, I have tried your script above by placing it in `/wp-content/themes/ directory` and directly running it and get a blank page.

Comment: @firefirehelphelp I see. Yes, I forgot to add the template name comment in there. I just edited to add that back into the example I posted for you.

Comment: @firefirehelphelp It can go wherever you like. Just be sure to encapsulate all of your PHP code inside PHP tags. I suggested an MU plugin file, but it could just as well go into a theme. Having said that, the original example that you posted had `wp-load.php` being require'd ahead of a `template_redirect` hook. That won't work because `wp-load.php` doesn't trigger `template_redirect`. The `wp-load.php` is a special way of loading only the WordPress framework w/o template output.

Comment: Hi jaswrks, thank you. I have placed the file within mu-plugins folder and removed reference to `wp-load.php`. Could you please help me with the following (1) Revised code is indicated in my original post. However, the re-direct function works strange. I am supposed to be redirected to `https://www.google.com.sg` but instead am directed to `http://mywebsite.com/https://www.google.com.sg`. (2) could you please explain why it was necessary to place it within `mu-plugins` folder? I read the link you posted and couldn't figure out why. The PHP file isn't a plugin.

Comment: Finally, placing the PHP file in the mu-plugin folder would affect all my other sites. Is it possible to have it such that it only affects one particular site? Thank you.

Comment: (1) Avoid using `get_site_url()` whenever you are redirecting to another full URL. Only use `get_site_url()` when you are redirecting to another `/path` on the same site.

Comment: (2) It is not important that it go into `mu-plugins`. You can put into a plugin file, or into `functions.php` for a theme. It just needs to get loaded by WordPress from a designated location, and not be a stand-alone PHP file.

Comment: (3) I'd go with the `mu-plugins` directory option, and then use [get_current_blog_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_blog_id/) and check if the redirection should apply, based on the current blog ID.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. For (1), what function should I be using instead? Thank you.

Comment: @firefirehelphelp I updated the code in my answer to help clarify for you.

Comment: Hi jaswrks, many thanks. The script works great on a single page. However, it doesn't work on multiple pages. Perhaps I have been thinking about this wrongly. My intention was to have multiple redirects from different pages. So I created multiple PHP files in the `mu-plugins` folder using your code and changing the page ID within. However, I encountered this fatal error as shown in the below comment. May I know how to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare geoip_redirect() (previously declared in /home/server1/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/GeoIPDetectionv 76.php:6) in /home/server1/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/GeoIPDetectionv 90.php on line 43`

Comment: It sounds like your function conflicts with the name of another, or that you've accidentally declared the function twice, or that you have two MU plugin files and both are being loaded. Can't declare two functions with same name is all.